# how to implement pagination for hashset in redis cache using nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis-cache

I have around 1000 records in hash-sets, i want to get only 0-50 records for first time and then 50-100 so on.

P.S. I am using node-redis. I want to find out whether redis supports pagination for hashes.

i have tried zrange but it doesn't work

```
cacheClient.zrange('searchkeycounts', 0, 50, function (err, reply) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(reply);
                                })
```

This gives the result:

```
{"result":"success","err":{"command":"ZRANGE","args":["searchkeycounts",0,5],"code":"WRONGTYPE"}}
```

The data looks like this:
[image: hash data format]

Comment: How does it not work? What sort of result are you getting?

Comment: @Haem {"result":"success","err":{"command":"ZRANGE","args":["searchkeycounts",0,5],"code":"WRONGTYPE"}}

Comment: Now edit that error message to your question.